# How to get data that is already present in input.txt file and find the highest salary with Department name using a Map<String,Integer> in java?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

**Salary of Newest Member of Dept**

In this problem, you have to modify an existing Java program that reads in some employee data, and does some processing on it.

The input is being read in from a file called input.txt, in this format:

```
22, Rajan Anand, Engineering, 1600000
23, Swati Patil, Testing, 800000
27, Vijay Chawda, Engineering, 800000
29, Basant Mahapatra, Engineering, 600000
32, Ajay Patel, Testing, 350000
34, Swaraj Birla, Testing, 350000
```

Each line consists of 4 fields "Employee ID," "Name," "Department," and "Salary." Here, "Employee ID" and "Salary" are integers, while "Name" and "Department" are strings that do not contain commas or newlines.

Currently, the existing program reads the input and creates an array of String from the lines of input. Then it calls a method processData on with this array, and prints the returned data to the output file. Unfortunately, processData currently does not do anything useful - it just returns an empty Map.

You have to modify processData find salary of the Employee who has the highest Employee ID in that department (because that represents the newest employee to join that department). Specifically, processData should return a Map where each key is the name of a department, and the value is the salary of the employee in that department who has the highest Employee ID.

If your program is run with the input given above, it should produce this output:

```
Engineering: 600000
Testing: 350000
```

This is because Basant Mahapatra has the highest employee ID (29) in the Engineering department and his salary is 600000, and Swaraj Birla has the highest employee ID (34) in the Testing department, and his salary is 350000.

Please make sure of the following:

•   All your changes must be inside the processData method. Do not make any changes to the rest of the program

•   Make sure processData returns the correct value

•   Do not add a package declaration, and do not change the name of the class.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

/* DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING ABOVE THIS LINE */
/* You may add any imports here, if you wish, but only from the 
   standard library */

/* Do not add a namespace declaration */
public class Main {
    public static Map<String,Integer> processData(ArrayList<String> array) {
        /* 
         * Modify this method to process `array` as indicated
         * in the question. At the end, return a Map containing
         * the appropriate values
         *
         * Please create appropriate classes, and use appropriate
         * data structures as necessary.
         *
         * Do not print anything in this method.
         *
         * Submit this entire program (not just this method)
         * as your answer
         */
        Map<String,Integer> retVal = new Map<String,Integer>();
       return retVal;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> inputData = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt")));
            while(in.hasNextLine())
                inputData.add(in.nextLine());
            Map<String,Integer> retVal = processData(inputData);
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt")));
            for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> e: retVal.entrySet())
                output.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue());
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO error in input.txt or output.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your issue? Expected vs observed output? So far it looks like you've just attached your assignment.

Comment: @sleepToken its not a assignment question.I got this question from one website, and i am unable to solve. That's why i posted here.

Comment: @KaranDodwani StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.  You can't just post requirements and expect someone to write the code for you.  You need to make a good-faith attempt to write the code yourself, and post here if you have any _specific_ issues with the code you've written.

Comment: @Jordan : I tried.Aftrer reading data from file i am unable to separate and compare as per the requirement.

Comment: Question header doesn't match with its contents: headers says about highest salary inside department but expected output shows salary of an employee with highest id inside department.
Also have you tried to google something like this: Java split string by <insert your delimiter here>?

Comment: @lvan Please read the question once again, question have all content required.. and yes i google about string but i didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/* DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING ABOVE THIS LINE */
/* You may add any imports here, if you wish, but only from the 
   standard library */

/* Do not add a namespace declaration */
public class Main {
    public static Map<String,Integer> processData(ArrayList<String> array) {
        String str[];
        int count=0;
        Map<String,Integer> res= new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    int ar[]= new int[100];
    int ar1[]= new int[100];
    int s1=0,s2=0;
```

//traversing arrayList

```
            for(String s : array){
                str= s.split(",");
```

//Storing all ID of Engineering Department in ar(Array)

```
                if(str[2].trim().equals("Engineering"))
```

{

```
                    ar[count]=(int)Integer.parseInt(str[0].trim());
```

//Searching for the highest ID in the ar(Array)

```
                    if(s1<=ar[count])
                        s1=ar[count];


                }
```

/*Storing all ID of Testing Department in ar1(Array) */

```
                if(str[2].trim().equals("Testing"))
                {


                    ar1[count]=(int)Integer.parseInt(str[0].trim());

        // Similarly Searching for the highest ID in the ar1(Array) 

                    if(s2<=ar1[count])
                        s2=ar1[count];

                }
        }
```

/*
again traversing  the array  to store department and salary in the res(HashMap)
of the ID we searched
*/

```
            for(String s : array){


                str= s.split(",");
                if(s1==(int)Integer.parseInt(str[0].trim())) {

                    Integer i=(Integer)Integer.parseInt(str[3].trim());
                    res.put("Engineering",i);

                }
                if(s2==(int)Integer.parseInt(str[0].trim())) {
                    Integer i=(Integer)Integer.parseInt(str[3].trim());
                    res.put("Testing",i);

                }

            }

            return res;
    }
```

//END

```
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> inputData = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\eclipse-workspace\\DesignPatterns\\src\\input.txt")));
            while(in.hasNextLine())
                inputData.add(in.nextLine());
            Map<String,Integer> retVal = processData(inputData);
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\eclipse-workspace\\DesignPatterns\\src\\output.txt")));
            for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> e: retVal.entrySet())
                output.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue());
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO error in input.txt or output.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please edit your answer and add some text to explain your code? That would make it much easier to understand your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Map<String, Integer> processData(ArrayList<String> array) {
    ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    array.forEach(empString -> {
        String s[] = empString.split(",");
        Employee emp = new Employee(Integer.parseInt(s[0].trim()),
                Integer.parseInt(s[3].trim()), s[1], s[2]);
        employees.add(emp);
    });

    Map<String, Employee> retVal = employees.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(
                    e -> e.getDepartment(),
                    collectingAndThen(maxBy(comparingInt(e -> e.getEmployeeId())), Optional::get)
            ));

    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    retVal.entrySet().forEach(stringEmployeeEntry -> {
        map.put(stringEmployeeEntry.getKey(), stringEmployeeEntry.getValue().getSalary());
    });
    return map;
}
```